# Android: How to package and deploy AIDL interfaces?

Tags: android, aidl

Our app exposes an Android service through an AIDL interface, which also depends on some children AIDL wrappers and parsable objects. What's the recommended approach for packaging these into a jar file for external consumption?

Can raw AIDL files go in the jar files, or do must they be first compiled into stubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can raw AIDL files go in the jar files

Well, they can, they just won't do anyone any good automatically.

> do must they be first compiled into stubs?

That is one possibility. I think it's safer if you would ship the AIDL file and tell them were to place it in their project.

I *think* the Android library project stuff now supports AIDL files, but I am not 100% certain. If it does, you could package your stuff as an Android library project, and the AIDL will be picked up automatically.